# Calculate date field by adding 12 hours to existing date field

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, datetime

I am trying to convert the following code to python. DATE_VAL is a date field. I want to add 12 hours to the date. I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 and python 2.7.1.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb\\lsr_reports6", "NEW_DATE", "DateAdd(\"h\", 12, [DATE_VAL])", "", "")
```

Not working:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb\\lsr_reports6", "NEW_DATE", "!DATE_VAL! + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the value !DATE_VAL! ArcMap returns a string. You have to therefore construct a datetime object in order to add a timedelta object. To do this, you need to know the format of the string returned by your Date field. By default, ArcMap uses your system date format.

In my case, I have the DATE_VAL field which returns dates in the format 14/10/2016 15:00:00. Therefore, to increment by 12 hours, I used the following expression:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(!DATE_VAL!,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
```

I recommend reading the [ArcMap Fundamentals of date fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm) and the python documentation on the datetime module, particularly [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 3):

See my blog on "[I've Saved Time in a Bottle.  How Do I Get it Back Out? - Doing More with Date Fields Using the Field Calculator and Python](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2016/07/01/ive-saved-time-in-a-bottle-how-do-i-get-it-back-out-doing-more-with-date-fields-using-the-field-calculator-and-python)"

As stupid as it may seem, when you use the Python option in the Field Calculator on a date field, the date is converted to a string and does not have any native date functionality.  You have to convert it back to a datetime before doing any date or time manipulations or formatting.  The Blog provides a method to do that and examples of date manipulations (although not the one you want to do specifically).